# Which matrix-functions are the derivatives of vector-functions?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $D$ be a bounded convex open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let
$f:D\to \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ be a bounded continuous function
(At the moment I am not interested in problems caused by
complicated geometry or unboundedness).

I am interested in the following general problem: What are the
conditions on $f$ under which $f$ is almost everywhere equal to
the derivative of some Lipschitz function $F:D\to\mathbb{R}^m$?

It is easy to check that the following condition is necessary and
sufficient.

**Condition 1.** For any two piecewise continuously differentiable
paths $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and
$\omega:[c,d]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ joining $x\in D$ and $y\in D$ the
equality
$$\int_a^b
f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt=\int_c^df(\omega(t))\omega'(s)ds$$ holds.

**Question 1.** Any other equivalent conditions?

**Question 2.** Are there any special classes of matrix-functions $f$
(in addition to complex-valued functions in the case $n=m=2$) for
which any interesting restatements of Condition 1 are known?

Answer (score 0):

Write $f$ as a $\mathbb R^m$-valued 1-form on $D$ like $f = (\sum_{j=1}^m f^i_j dx^j)_{i=1}^n$,
then vanishing of the exterior derivative 
$$
df = \Big(\sum_{j,k=1}^m \frac{\partial f^i_j}{\partial x^k} dx^k\wedge dx^j\Big)_{i=1}^n
$$
is equivalent to your wish on subsets $U$ of $D$ with $H^1_{\text{de Rham}}(U)=0$.

Comment: Note that the function $f$ is only assumed to be continuous, so partial derivatives in this answer, a priori, do not exist.